# How to get returnURL with all queryParams in Angular?

Tags: angular

The url is http://127.0.0.1:4200/app/login/123456?returnUrl=%2Flive-score%3Fleague%3Dworldcup&v=1.23

this is my code to get the returnUrl.

`this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';`

i got the returnUrl "/live-score?league=worldcup"

I want to get full url like below

`/live-score?league=worldcup&v=1.23`

Comment: `&v=1.23` should be encoded as well, I think you are not encoding it and then it belong to your application queryParams.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get all query parameters.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((queryParams) => {
      const params = queryParams;

      //you stuff
    });
  }
```